# Center content of page

Tags: html, css

How to put the content of the page in its center?

## [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y42Pf/25/)

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>a</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>cxwxc</div>
    </body>
</html>

div {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

That's how I'm proceeding, but that wouldn't work. How to fix it please?

Comment: There are literally thousands of places you can find this information, just google "how to center css"

Comment: margin auto only works if you give it a width or max-width. Of course,divs are 100% wide by default.

Comment: Also , text should always be in a proper text tag...which a div is not.

Comment: I'm sure that the div would be centered if you have it a width; by default, div's have 100% width.

Comment: I would look into the flex reference on the W3C website, I posted a reference below. This is not fully fully supported but is good to get into.

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide a width to make it work...

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>a</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <p style ="width:100px">cxwxc</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
p {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
text-align: center;
```

is your friend.

http://jsfiddle.net/Y42Pf/26/

To center the entire div with its contents, you need to specify a width for it.  [By default, an element's width property is auto, which is calculated by the browser.](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#the-width-property)  In your case, your div's width was set to 100% of width of its parent element, which happened to take up the entire container.  Because of this, your margin-left and margin-right properties resolved to zero, and your div was technically centered.

Give the div an arbitrary width and try again, and you'll see that it is centered.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Y42Pf/28/

Comment: I don't want to center the text, but all of the container's elements

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried text-align:center; on your div element. See http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-align.asp

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: table`.  It is truly your friend when you want content shrinkwrapped and centered at the same time on the line of its own: http://jsfiddle.net/Sft7x/.

```
div {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
    outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to put like this:

```
div {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

it happen because your text is relative to your body, but your body is only your text, so it will be in the begin of page, setting like this we set the div to the center of page.

Answer (score 0):

For centering div on the page

```
div {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

For centering text inside div add `text-align` property

```
div {
  width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```